# I get a permission denied error with my firebase database values but only when I read image urls?

Tags: jquery, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

These are my database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
```

There are image urls in this child

```
  "images":{
    "$uid":{
      ".read":true,
      ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
    }
  },
```

There are also image urls in this child

```
      "profile":{
        "$uid":{
          ".read":true,
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That was my database code

This is how I use it in my swift code:

```
databaserEF = Database.database.reference.child("users").child("profile").child("images").child(userID!)
 databaserEF.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let photo = dictionary!["HEADSHOT"] as? String
            if photo != "nothing"{
                let url = URL(string: photo!)
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, repone, error) in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
        })
```

And this how I organized it in the database

[image]

Comment: Could you please post some example of how you're storing your data and how you are trying to query it?

Comment: How do you initialize `databaserEF`? Please consider creating how to create a completely standalone reproduction of the problem to aid in troubleshooting. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DennisAlund I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an error in how you reference your data.

Your reference declaration currently looks like this:

```
Database.database.reference.child("users").child("profile").child("images").child(userID!)
```

Although your database structure suggests that you should remove the `.child("profile")` and instead declare your reference like this:

```
Database.database.reference.child("users").child("images").child(userID!)
```

to retrieve

```
{
  'BODYSHOT': 'nothing',
  'HEADSHOT': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...',
  'SWIMSHOT': 'nothing'
}
```